# initialize useState with data from firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm looking for a way in initialize a useState object with the value that is fetched from firestore

```
getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
    const initEmail = doc.data().email
    console.log(initEmail)
    return initEmail
})

const [email, setEmail] = useState(initEmail)
```

how would i go about doing this?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Can you please provide more information?

Answer (score 1):

You should call the setter function for the state inside the asynchronous callback:

```
getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
    const initEmail = doc.data().email
    console.log(initEmail)
    setEmail(initEmail);
})

const [email, setEmail] = useState(initEmail, "initial value for email")
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do it as page loads, you should use useEffect,

```
useEffect(() => {
        getDoc(docRef).then((doc) => {
                const initEmail = doc.data().email
                console.log(initEmail)
                setEmail(initEmail);
        })
}, [])
```